# What does "vinyasa" mean?

Tags: meditation

Since my childhood my grandmother taught me that the meaning of Vinyasa means to see everything less complicated. My grandma pass away 6 months ago, and i want to make a tattoo that reminds me how she was and what she taught me, and i always found the word vinyasa had a special meaning.

Well, i already had the idea to make it, the place and the price too. But before making a mark for the rest of my life i want to make sure that what i was going to tattoo it was what i really think, so i searched it up. Well i found only one site that talks about the meaning that my grandma taught, and i dont know if that can be a real meaning for vinyasa. I want to know what vinyasa means. Sorry for my english, it's not my first language.

Comment: Hello Gustavo and welcome to Buddhism SE. I edited your question a bit. If not agreeable please roll-back. Enjoy your time here.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Vinyāsa is not a Pali word, and is more about yoga (unrelated to Buddhist dhamma).

There is a Sanskrit dictionary here:
https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/vinyasa

Comment: Vinyasa does not seem to have any connection with yoga or the meaning referred to in the question.But sanskrit words can be interpreted differently.